# WP 8 Speech Recognizer in Portuguese

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-to-text

I'm trying to implement a STT(SpeechToText) app in VS2012 Express that should recognize Portuguese phrases and show it in a TextBlock. I've already tried to change Speech Settings on the Emulator to Portuguese, but when I run the program, it says that "the language is not supported". Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not all even installed languages support dictation recognition.

You can get supported languages list like follow:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<SpeechRecognizerInformation> speechRecognizers = InstalledSpeechRecognizers.All;
```

If I'm not mistaken only `pt-BR` is supported. So you may need change region to Brazil to make it work in Portuguese.